# Ruby regex into array of hashes but need to drop a key/val pair

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I'm trying to parse a file containing a name followed by a hierarchy path.  I want to take the named regex matches, turn them into Hash keys, and store the match as a hash.  Each hash will get pushed to an array (so I'll end up with an array of hashes after parsing the entire file.  This part of the code is working except now I need to handle bad paths with duplicated hierarchy (top_* is always the top level).  It appears that if I'm using named backreferences in Ruby I need to name *all* of the backreferences.  I have gotten the match working in Rubular but now I have the `p1` backreference in my resultant hash.

Question: What's the easiest way to not include the `p1` key/value pair in the hash?  My method is used in other places so we can't assume that `p1` always exists.  Am I stuck with dropping each key/value pair in the array after calling the s_ary_to_hash method?

NOTE: I'm keeping this question to try and solve the specific issue of ignoring certain hash keys in my method.  The regex issue is now in this ticket: [Ruby regex - using optional named backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470962/ruby-regex-using-optional-named-backreferences)

UPDATE: Regex issue is solved, the hier is now always stored in the named 'hier' group.  The only item remaining is to figure out how to drop the 'p1' key/value if it exists prior to creating the Hash.

Example file:

```
name1 top_cat/mouse/dog/top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse
new12 top_ab12/hat[1]/top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool
tops  top_bat/car[0]
ab123 top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog
```

Expected output:

```
[{:name => "name1", :hier => "top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse"},
 {:name => "new12", :hier => "top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool"},
 {:name => "tops",  :hier => "top_bat/car[0]"},
 {:name => "ab123", :hier => "top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog"}]
```

Code snippet:

```
def s_ary_to_hash(ary, regex)
  retary = Array.new
  ary.each {|x| (retary << Hash[regex.match(x).names.map{|key| key.to_sym}.zip(regex.match(x).captures)]) if regex.match(x)}
  return retary
end

regex = %r{(?<name>\w+) (?<p1>[\w\/\[\]]+)?(?<hier>(\k<p1>.*)|((?<= ).*$))}
h_ary = s_ary_to_hash(File.readlines(filename), regex)
```

Comment: Do you have a `.html/.xml` file? If so , please use `nokogiri`.

Comment: Agreed, but this is not HTML or XML... it's a dump from another program that I can't touch.

Comment: Greg, regardless of the regex you use, consider replacing the three lines of `s_ary_to_hash` with `ary.each_with_object([]) { |x, retry| .... }`.

Comment: Good tip, I had forgotten about the `|x, retry|` way of collecting results.  Thanks!

Comment: @Greg, when I test your code, I don't get the last line of your expected output.  Could you check that?

Comment: You're correct, it's busted.  I can't find a way to store the result into :hier directly for the 3rd case.  Alex has the best solution so far if I make a 2nd pass to assign `:hier = :p1 if (hier).nil?`

Comment: After asking another question and playing around in Rubular I was able to get the lookbehind working.  Now the expected output is correct except I have p1 key/value pairs in the hash.

Answer (score 2):

What about this regex ?

```
^(?<name>\S+)\s+(?<p1>top_.+?)(?:\/(?<hier>\k<p1>(?:\[.+?\])?.+))?$
```

#### Demo

http://rubular.com/r/awEP9Mz1kB

#### Sample code

```rb
def s_ary_to_hash(ary, regex, mappings)
   retary = Array.new

   for item in ary
      tmp = regex.match(item)
      if tmp then
         hash = Hash.new
         retary.push(hash)
         mappings.each { |mapping|
            mapping.map { |key, groups|
              for group in group
                 if tmp[group] then
                     hash[key] = tmp[group]
                     break
                 end
              end 
            }
         }
      end
   end

  return retary
end

regex = %r{^(?<name>\S+)\s+(?<p1>top_.+?)(?:\/(?<hier>\k<p1>(?:\[.+?\])?.+))?$}
h_ary = s_ary_to_hash(
   File.readlines(filename), 
   regex,
   [ 
      {:name => ['name']},
      {:hier => ['hier','p1']}
   ]
)

puts h_ary
```

#### Output

```
{:name=>"name1", :hier=>"top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse\r"}
{:name=>"new12", :hier=>"top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool\r"}
{:name=>"tops", :hier=>"top_bat/car[0]"}
```

#### Discussion

Since Ruby 2.0.0 doesn't support branch reset, I have built a solution that add some more power to the `s_ary_to_hash` function. It now admits a third parameter indicating how to build the final array of hashes.

This third parameter is an array of hashes. Each hash in this array has one key (`K`) corresponding to the key in the final array of hashes. `K` is associated with an array containing the named group to use from the passed regex (second parameter of `s_ary_to_hash` function).

If a group equals `nil`, `s_ary_to_hash` skips it for the next group.

If all groups equal `nil`, `K` is not pushed on the final array of hashes.
Feel free to modify `s_ary_to_hash` if this isn't a desired behavior.

Comment: Alex, when I run this I get an array of three hashes.  The first two are the same as in "Expected output".  The third, however, is `{:name=>"tops", :hier=>"top_bat/car[0]"}]`.  Greg, is the "Expected output" correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland do you need to drop `top_` in the third hash ?

Comment: Oops, I had a type in my expected output.  It's corrected now.

Comment: Alex, that regex doesn't meet the criteria of dropping the duplicated hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, :p1 still appears in my Hash (tested in irb).  My regex functionality is not the problem, it's that it's storing the p1 key/value pair in my hash.

Original question --> What's the easiest way to not include the p1 key/value pair in the hash

Comment: OK, I see your discussion section.  I agree that your method will work but I'm hoping someone can find a way to do this in 1 pass (e.g. no re-assignment & cleanup).  Do you know of a way to assign it into :hier to begin with?  Perl supports branch reset groups which could solve this regex dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I've changed the method `s_ary_to_hash` to conform with what I now understand to be the criterion for excluding directories, namely, directory `d` is to be excluded if there is a downstream directory with the same name, or the same name followed by a non-negative integer in brackets.  I've applied that to all directories, though I made have misunderstood the question; perhaps it should apply to the first.

```
data =<<THE_END
name1 top_cat/mouse/dog/top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse
new12 top_ab12/hat/top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool
tops  top_bat/car[0]
ab123 top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog
THE_END

text = data.split("\n")

def s_ary_to_hash(ary)
  ary.map do |s| 
    name, _, downstream_path = s.partition(' ').map(&:strip)
    arr = []
    downstream_dirs = downstream_path.split('/')
    downstream_dirs.each {|d| puts "'#{d}'"}
    while downstream_dirs.any? do
      dir = downstream_dirs.shift
      arr << dir unless downstream_dirs.any? { |d|
        d == dir || d =~ /#{dir}\[\d+\]/ }
    end     
    { name: name, hier: arr.join('/') }
  end   
end

s_ary_to_hash(text)
  # => [{:name=>"name1", :hier=>"top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse"},
  #     {:name=>"new12", :hier=>"top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool"},
  #     {:name=>"tops", :hier=>"top_bat/car[0]"},
  #     {:name=>"ab123", :hier=>"top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog"}]
```

The exclusion criterion is implement in `downstream_dirs.any? { |d| d == dir || d =~ /#{dir}\[\d+\]/ }`, where `dir` is the directory that is being tested and `downstream_dirs` is an array of all the downstream directories.  (When `dir` is the last directory, `downstream_dirs` is empty.)  Localizing it in this way makes it easy to test and change the exclusion criterion.  You could shorten this to a single regex and/or make it a method:

```
dir exclude_dir?(dir, downstream_dirs)
  downstream_dirs.any? { |d| d == dir || d =~ /#{dir}\[\d+\]/ }end
end
```

Comment: Hi Cary.  I want to take the 1st element in the 2nd string  (elements delineated by slashes) and see if it exists anywhere in the remaining string.  If it does, I want my returned match to contain everything from that 2nd location onwards. If it does not, I want my match to contain the entire original 2nd string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non regexp solution:

```
result = string.each_line.map do |line|
  name, path = line.split(' ')
  path = path.split('/')
  last_occur_of_root = path.rindex(path.first)
  path = path[last_occur_of_root..-1]
  {name: name, heir: path.join('/')}
end
```