# Ruby regex - using optional named backreferences

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a Ruby regex that will return a set of named matches.  If the first element (defined by slashes) is found anywhere later in the string then I want the match to return that 2nd match onward.  Otherwise, return the whole string.  The closest I've gotten is  `(?<p1>top_\w+).*?(?<hier>\k<p1>.*)` which doesn't work for the 3rd item.  I've tried regex ifthen-else constructs but Rubular says it's invalid.  I've tried `(?<p1>[\w\/]+?)(?<hier>\k<p1>.*)` which correct splits the 1st and 4th lines but doesn't work for the others.  Please note: I want all results to return as the same named reference so I can iterate through "hier".

Input:

```
top_cat/mouse/dog/top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse
top_ab12/hat[1]/top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool
top_bat/car[0]
top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog
```

Output:

```
hier = top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse
hier = top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool
hier = top_bat/car[0]
hier = top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The reason it does not match the second line is because the second instance of hat does not end with a slash, but the first instance does.

### Solution

Specify that there is a slash between the first and second match

### Regex

`(top_.*)/(\1.*$)|(^.*$)`

### Replacement

`hier = \2\3`

### Example

[Regex101 Permalink](http://regex101.com/r/yS0eL8)

---

### More info on the Alternation token

To explain how the `|` token works in regex, see the example: `abc|def`
What this regex means in plain english is:

- Match either the regex below **(attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)**

  - Match the characters `abc` literally
- Or match the regex below **(the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)**

  - Match the characters `def` literally

**Example**
Regex: `alpha|alphabet`
If we had a phrase "I know the alphabet", only the word `alpha` would be matched.
However, if we changed the regex to `alphabet|alpha`, we would match `alphabet`.

So you can see, alternation works in a **left-to-right** fashion.

Comment: Well, this wasn't exactly what I wanted but it led me down the path to fixing the regex (your use of the | ).  `(?<p1>[\w\/\[\]]+)?(?<hier>(\k<p1>.*)|(^.*$))` will always store the desired match into the named group "hier".

Comment: The alternation is simply there in case the first bit doesn't match, but hey, if that works - awesome! :)

Comment: Excellent answer.  It gave me new insight into the use of `|`.

Comment: Thanks! I've just added even more about that token for others to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
paths = %w(
  top_cat/mouse/dog/top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse
  top_ab12/hat/top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool
  top_bat/car[0]
  top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog
  test/test
)

paths.each do |path|
  md = path.match(/^([^\/]*).*\/(\1(\/.*|$))/)
  heir = md ? md[2] : path
  puts heir
end
```

Output:

```
top_cat/mouse/dog/elephant/horse
top_ab12/hat[1]/path0_top_ab12/top_ab12path1/cool
top_bat/car[0]
top_2/top_1/top_3/top_4/dog
test
```